# Differential Amplifier small signal analysis

Tags: amplifier, common-mode, small-signal

I am having trouble doing the analysis the small signal model of this circuit:

[image]

So far, I have come up with this this circuit for the small signal analysis:
[image]

However, I can't come up with a formula for the circuit gain. I tried to split the circuit in half by removing the wire between the source of the transistors (Assuming the transistors are the same, the circuit is symmetric), but I ended up with a gain of 0. I am wondering if this methodology is good.

Comment: *I tried to split the circuit in half by removing the wire between the source of the transistors* Good, but what did you do besides that? Consider what the voltage at the common-source point will be when we assume that the input voltage is **fully differential**. Also, your circuit drawings show "Vin" and "Vout" at both inputs and outputs. That would mean they're connected (Vin on the left is shorted to Vin on the right). I'm guessing that that's not what you want. I would use \$V_{inp}\$ at the left and  \$V_{inn}\$ at the right. Same with the outputs.

Comment: You might also want to search on Google for "differential NMOS pair small signal" and you should find plenty of lectures explaining this as it is a very common exercise when learning small signal analysis.